# xxx is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extend spark 3.0 Datasource API V2.

when i execute sqls:

1. create table spark_catalog.default.test USING xxx   (success)
2. select * from spark_catalog.default.test  (xxx is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source )

I have found that it is because I should extend `SchemaRelationProvider` or `CreatableRelationProvider` in datasource, However, it is v1 api.

what should i do if i want to only use v2 api ?

thx